# My computer hangs almost every time I stand up from the chair

Tags: freeze, crash

I have experienced some very weird behaviour from my computer recently. Almost every time I stand up from the chair it enters in a weird state where only a hard reset can bring it back to normality.

This started some time ago when we moved to a new office location and the computer was relocated to a new building. I suspect that it has some loose wires somewhere, but regardless if I shake it or do any other physical movements to it, it does not react like this, just continues to work normally. If I stand up, most of the time it crashes.

The OS running on it is Fedora 25 (but it had exactly the same behaviour with Arch Linux and Linux Mint also).

This crash can happen anytime, it does not even need to have the OS booted.

Here is the output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 Northbridge only single slot PCI-e GFX Hydra part (rev 02)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GFX port 0)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GPP Port 0)
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GPP Port 1)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GPP Port 2)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GPP Port 3)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 41)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller (rev 40)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control
02:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
04:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6315 Series Firewire Controller
05:00.0 SATA controller: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB361 AHCI/IDE (rev 02)
05:00.1 IDE interface: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB361 AHCI/IDE (rev 02)
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF106 [GeForce GTS 450] (rev a1)
06:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

and `lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 1038:1369 SteelSeries ApS 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Please find a short video demonstrating this strange behaviour:

https://youtu.be/chbm1plYS2M

In the video you can see one second the desktop,and the next second it disappears, and there is the "No signal" message on the screen, meaning the computer went away. It is NOT the laptop on the desk, but this one below:

[image]

Any ideas on how to identify what might be wrong with it? I am more than happy to provide further information if required.

*Edit* The floor is solid concrete, with a gray, wall to wall carpet on it, so no cables underneath if I'm correct. All the cables (network and electricity) are from this pole, coming from above:

[image]

The pole is shared with others people's computers and hardware, however they are not affected.

*Edit* Network: After the computer goes into the hang stage it does not respond to pings.

Comment: I can't see the video due to work, but, some thoughts. I assume it's not occurring from any where in the room? If you move the chair to the far corner of the room, does the same issue occur? If not, then it's likely vibration or similar - there is a lose/faulty cable which is affected as you move. I doubt it's any type of static, but you could put a book between the case and floor. Or, you have cables under the floor board which is being affected some how

Comment: Have you tried starting the system without sitting?

Comment: @Carrein Yes, I have. It works nicely ... but after a while I have to sit down/stand up/walk away from the table, and when this happens it crashes again most of the time.

Comment: @fritzone try placing the CPU in the different orientation, maybe the feet of the CPU have something to do with it.

Comment: Or try placing some books beneath the PC.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the most entertaining questions I've seen all day. I've watched your video a bunch of times on loop, and it's not at all clear what's causing this from that clip.

However, I see a lot of cables hanging around on the floor - is the floor flexible and affected by your movement? You may be flexing a very faulty cable and causing an electrical short in - something. You might want to get under there and manhandle each one of those cables until the machine flips out (hopefully it will).

Also - are you sure it's crashing, or is it just no longer outputting video? Try getting into the box via SSH when this happens, and you might be able to see the output of `dmesg` to determine what in the world is happening. Though if it's hard crashing, you won't get much diagnostic information out of the software - almost certainly nothing, that is.

It's definitely not static or any other phenomena like that, I can assure you. I wish I could provide more concrete answers, but there just isn't much to go on here.